# DataFrame behaving oddly?

Tags: python

Im going nuts here, trying to understand why this code gives me different results... The mean value calculation differs, even though i put in the (i think) same numbers?

```
max_underlag = 0.0
df.loc[df.Gräskvot < 1-max_underlag, 'Gräskvot'] = 1-max_underlag
df.loc[df.Gräskvot > 1+max_underlag, 'Gräskvot'] = 1+max_underlag
df.loc[df.Plastkvot < 1-max_underlag, 'Plastkvot'] = 1-max_underlag
df.loc[df.Plastkvot > 1+max_underlag, 'Plastkvot'] = 1+max_underlag

print(df.loc[:, ("mp_h", "mp_b", "Gräskvot", "Plastkvot")].tail())

#df.mp_h = (df.mp_h / df.Plastkvot).where((df.Underlag == "Plast"), df.mp_h / df.Gräskvot)
#df.mp_b = (df.mp_b * df.Plastkvot).where((df.Underlag == "Plast"), df.mp_b * df.Gräskvot)

print("\n",df.loc[:, ("mp_h", "mp_b", "Gräskvot", "Plastkvot")].tail())

df["mp_snitt_h_framåt"]     = round(df.groupby(['Hemmalag'])['mp_h'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift()), 2)
df["mp_snitt_h_bakåt"]      = round(df.groupby(['Hemmalag'])['mp_b'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift()), 2)

print("\n",df.loc[:, ("mp_snitt_h_framåt", "mp_snitt_h_bakåt")].tail())
```

The code give me this result:

```
 mp_h  mp_b  Gräskvot  Plastkvot
777  0.68  0.66       1.0        1.0
778  0.87  1.13       1.0        1.0
779  2.40  2.40       1.0        1.0
780   NaN   NaN       1.0        1.0
781  1.12  0.88       1.0        1.0

  mp_h  mp_b  Gräskvot  Plastkvot
777  0.68  0.66       1.0        1.0
778  0.87  1.13       1.0        1.0
779  2.40  2.40       1.0        1.0
780   NaN   NaN       1.0        1.0
781  1.12  0.88       1.0        1.0

  mp_snitt_h_framåt  mp_snitt_h_bakåt
777               1.79              1.42
778               1.34              1.34
779               1.59              1.80
780               1.61              1.54
781               1.41              1.72
```

When i remove the #:s i should get the same results because "GRäskvot" and "Plastkvot" is set to 1 and there fore don't changes the "mp_h" or "mp_b".

```
 mp_h  mp_b  Gräskvot  Plastkvot
777  0.68  0.66       1.0        1.0
778  0.87  1.13       1.0        1.0
779  2.40  2.40       1.0        1.0
780   NaN   NaN       1.0        1.0
781  1.12  0.88       1.0        1.0

  mp_h  mp_b  Gräskvot  Plastkvot
777  0.68  0.66       1.0        1.0
778  0.87  1.13       1.0        1.0
779  2.40  2.40       1.0        1.0
780   NaN   NaN       1.0        1.0
781  1.12  0.88       1.0        1.0

  mp_snitt_h_framåt  mp_snitt_h_bakåt
777               1.79              1.37
778               1.32              1.31
779               1.53              1.83
780               1.60              1.61
781               1.31              1.70
```

Since mp_h and mp_b are the same, how come the "mp_snitt_h_framåt" and   "mp_snitt_h_bakåt" differs? i guess i'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: You can use `np.clip` to simplify lines 2–5.

Comment: What is `print(len(df.Gräskvot) - df.Gräskvot.abs().sum(), len(df.Plastkvot) - df.Plastkvot.abs().sum())`?

Comment: I get the same result, 94.0 94.0

I have also controlled count to make sure the number of elements are the same.

Comment: I would say the first result is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had a bunch on NaNs in "Gräskvot" and "Plastkvot" wich of course created a bunch of NaNs in "mp_h" and  "mp_b"

A stupid misstake that caused me a lot of headache... Sorry for wasting your time!